# Google Sheet SUM DATEVALUE QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I have a simple QUERY with a SUM, which I have used in other sheets, that should show SUM if the datevalue in the sheet matches a parameter that is also a datevalue...

I cant figure out WHY this returns no values. If i take out the date parameters in the query it returns all the values. WHAT?

```html
=QUERY('Do Not Delete'!E:X,
"SELECT T, SUM(I)
WHERE E = 'paid'
AND W >= '"&$E$2&"'
AND W <= '"&$E$3&"'
GROUP BY T", -1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out since the number values are pure numbers I needed to get rid of the ' ' around them in the QUERY

```html
=QUERY('Do Not Delete'!E:X,
"SELECT T, SUM(I)
WHERE E = 'paid'
AND W >= "&$E$2&"
AND W <= "&$E$3&"
GROUP BY T", -1)
```